# A simple riddle

Tags: riddle, science

> When you are on top of tree and have no support, you had to trust me.

What am I?

Comment: Just a warning, these really short riddles are extremely likely to be flagged as 'too broad'. If you feel that there is only one reasonable answer, then it's fine, but when you're starting out, it's better to write more clues or include more tags to help explain away unintended answers.

Comment: @Roland But if I write more clue, I have said the answer.

Comment: @lucas If you are not sure what hints to give, you should also explain to each answerer why their answer is 'incorrect' or ill-fitting.

Comment: Is it deliberate that you didn't write "I cannot work" in your last hint? Will it no longer make sense then?

Comment: @nicael Yes it is deliberate. I approximately said the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't accept an answer that doesn't explain the hints, especially if you think the riddle is easy.  And, if you do (accept an answer that doesn't explain the hints), then **you** should explain them yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to trust my

> instincts

And I don't care if you support this answer, because

> my instinct was that the answer is "instincts"

---

Well, it can't be

> friction

because it often does work, and this question lacks the [science](/questions/tagged/science) tag

Comment: How was my riddle? :-)

Comment: @lucas But since when can't it do work?

Comment: As a physicist, I reject your acceptance of my answer and deem this riddle a danger to the education of the public.

Answer (score 4):

What am I?

> Gravity

Because without me

> You would be in constant danger of floating into space

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> a Bank? :p

Explanation

> Since you have nobody or nothing to support you, you take credit ("trust"). I doubt it's a right answer though, because you could interpret the riddle rather differently.

Answer (score 3):

It could be also

> a hint

Because

> Without any answers in the thread, which could support you by giving you an idea for your own answer, the only things you can trust are the hints. It also happens to be useful and necessary, but sometimes it would spoil the riddle.

Comment: nice answer...                    .

Answer (score 2):

Too broad answer:

> walking stick

this:

> [image]

Comment: You probably want to provide an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

May be

> Advice

When you have no support, you had to trust me.

> When you have no support you have to trust on advices given to you.

Hint 1:

> Its mostly useful but you hate taking them sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

> the simplest answer would be "choice"  *When you have no support, you had to trust me.*  it says when you have no support(there is or nothing that can help you accomplish the task) so u always have a choice to do something other than that task which u can accomplish without any support.

OR

> If that is a religious question then the answer is simply THE GOD.

Comment: You should provide an explanation.